# Sending multiple variables from controller to view with Laravel

Tags: laravel-5

Can someone please help me fixing this? I am getting a 'Undefined variable: roles' error on the view with this in the controller:

public function create()
    {

```
    $offices = Office::pluck('name', 'id');
    $roles = Role::pluck('name', 'id');

    return view('gebruikers.create')->with('offices', $offices, 'roles', $roles);
}
```

Comment: try  return view('gebruikers.create')->with('offices', $offices)->with( 'roles', $roles);

Answer (score 0):

According to the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/views), "As an alternative to passing a complete array of data to the view helper function, you may use the with method to add individual pieces of data to the view:"

In the code you posted your trying to post multiple pieces of data. This can be done by calling the `with` method multiple times.

```
 return view('gebruikers.create')->with('offices', $offices)->with( 'roles', $roles);
```